# Angular 2 and FireBase messagning - unable to register

Tags: javascript, rest, angular, web

I am developing Angular 2 web app and want to register Firebase Messaging and obtain token.

I am using angularfire2 for Angular 2. I use Angular ng serve local development environment.
Unfortunatelly the browser console shows me below errors:

> V
>   browserErrorMessage
>   :
>   "Failed to register a ServiceWorker: A bad HTTP response code (404) was received when fetching the script."
>   code
>   :
>   "messaging/failed-serviceworker-registration"
>   message
>   :
>   "Messaging: We are unable to register the default service worker. Failed to register a ServiceWorker: A bad HTTP response code (404) was received when fetching the script. (messaging/failed-serviceworker-registration)."
>   stack
>   :
>   "FirebaseError: Messaging: We are unable to register the default service worker. Failed to register a ServiceWorker: A bad HTTP response code (404) was received when fetching the script. (messaging/failed-serviceworker-registration).↵    at http://localhost:4200/vendor.bundle.js:96468:225↵    at ZoneDelegate.invoke (http://localhost:4200/vendor.bundle.js:102953:26)↵    at Object.onInvoke (http://localhost:4200/vendor.bundle.js:33052:37)↵    at ZoneDelegate.invoke (http://localhost:4200/vendor.bundle.js:102952:32)↵    at Zone.run (http://localhost:4200/vendor.bundle.js:102824:43)↵    at http://localhost:4200/vendor.bundle.js:103246:57↵    at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (http://localhost:4200/vendor.bundle.js:102986:35)↵    at Object.onInvokeTask (http://localhost:4200/vendor.bundle.js:33043:37)↵    at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (http://localhost:4200/vendor.bundle.js:102985:40)↵    at Zone.runTask (http://localhost:4200/vendor.bundle.js:102862:47)↵    at drainMicroTaskQueue (http://localhost:4200/vendor.bundle.js:103144:35)"
>   **proto**
>   :
>   Error

Below is the code of my service.

```html
import { Inject, Injectable } from "@angular/core";
import { FirebaseApp } from "angularfire2";
import * as firebase from 'firebase';

@Injectable()
export class FirebaseMessagingService {

  private messaging: firebase.messaging.Messaging;

  constructor( @Inject(FirebaseApp) private firebaseApp: firebase.app.App) {
    console.log("FirebaseMessagingService init...");
    this.messaging = firebase.messaging(this.firebaseApp);
    
  }


  init() {

    

    this.messaging.requestPermission()
      .then(() => {
        this.onFirebaseInitialized();
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log("FirebaseMessagingService requestPermission error:" + error);

      });
  }

  private onFirebaseInitialized() {
    console.log("FirebaseMessagingService initialized");

    /*this.messaging.setBackgroundMessageHandler(message => {
      
    })*/

    this.getToken();


    // Callback fired if Instance ID token is updated.
    this.messaging.onTokenRefresh(() => {
      this.getToken();
    });

    

    this.messaging.onMessage((payload) => {
      console.log("Message received. ", payload);
      // ...
    });
    


  }

  getToken() {
    this.messaging.getToken()
      .then((currentToken) => {
        console.log('getToken() received');
        if (currentToken) {
          this.sendTokenToServer(currentToken);
          this.updateUIForPushEnabled(currentToken);
        } else {
          // Show permission request.
          console.log('No Instance ID token available. Request permission to generate one.');
          // Show permission UI.
          this.updateUIForPushPermissionRequired();
          this.setTokenSentToServer(false);
        }
      })
      .catch(function (err) {
        console.log('An error occurred while retrieving token. ', err);
        //this.showToken('Error retrieving Instance ID token. ', err);
        //this.setTokenSentToServer(false);
      });
  }


  sendTokenToServer(token) {

  }

  updateUIForPushEnabled(token) {

  }

  updateUIForPushPermissionRequired() {

  }

  setTokenSentToServer(isSent: boolean) {

  }

  

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to register a ServiceWorker:

1. Create a web app manifest as described here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/js/client
2. Create a service worker file, as described in the following section *Receive Messages*.
3. Load the two files. For example, in index.html:

   ```
     <link rel="manifest" href="/manifest.json">

     <script>
       if ('serviceWorker' in navigator) {
         navigator.serviceWorker.register('/firebase-messaging-sw.js').then(function(registration) {
           // Registration was successful
           console.log('ServiceWorker registration successful with scope: ', registration.scope);
         }).catch(function(err) {
           // registration failed :(
           console.log('ServiceWorker registration failed: ', err);
         });
       }
      </script>
   ```

This blog post helped me in the process: https://houssein.me/progressive-angular-applications

Note: be aware that Chrome has some issues regarding firebase messaging. If you don't see a response from `firebase.messaging(firebaseApp).getToken()` try opening the Service Workers section in the dev tools under Application tab, unregister the application's service worker, and reload. On Firefox there shouldn't be an issue.

Answer (score 1):

Most likely the *firebase-messaging-sw.js* is missing in the compiled app code:

- Make sure you have a file named *firebase-messaging-sw.js* in the ***src*** folder. Can be an empty file.
- Make sure when you run your app this file can be served from **'/'**, if using **angular cli** modify the content of the .angular-cli.json file to include the firebase-messaging-sw.js in the compile code:

> ```
> // ..... .angular-cli.json
> "apps": [{
>     "root": "src",
>     "outDir": "dist",
>     "assets": [
>       "assets",
>       "favicon.ico",
>       "firebase-messaging-sw.js" // this will copy this file in the root path of the compilation folder
>     ],
> // ..... more config options
> ```

Answer (score 0):

You must add `firebase-messaging-sw.js` in www dir, because the page looks for `http://localhost/firebase-messaging-sw.js` instead of our project dir.